# want to create ETL jobs (insert / update the records ) by using AWS Glue studio. its possible or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, etl, aws-glue

I want to create ETL (Insert / Update the records from one table to another)using AWS Glue studio. that's possible or not?

Comment: which database are you using?  If its myql / RDS Aurora, you can try pymysql / mysql.connector library, and use "INSERT INTO TABLE....ON DUPLICATE KEY...." for insert/update.  Please provide the db name so it would be helpful for appropriate solutions / suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using RDS Oracle Database. I made aws glue job using AWS glue studio for data transformation and insert records successfully but i can't able to check IF exists condition for available records and update those by latest records.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not available now.
However, the upcoming feature on governed table will bring that capability out. Now it is in preview phase.